# Nginx Erro 502 gateway to find cause

Tags: nginx, gateway

I have a nginx server where you have wordpress blog

But I'm 502 gateway error problems the error happens, and disappears during the day several times.

I wonder how can I do to investigate the nginx what ta causing the error.

I disabled all wordpress plugins but the error remains.

Comment: Have you taken a look at Nginx' error logs? Whatever went wrong will have left a trace there

Comment: In my error.log it appears that many times what can be?

2016/03/19 14:55:24 [error] 4999#0: *41573 connect() to unix:/data/php5514/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 50.30.44.106, server: mywebsite.com, request: "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/data/php5514/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "mywebsite.com"